# Border-bottom showing on top

Tags: css

How do I solve this:

```
.dropdownmenulist li a:hover {
cursor: pointer;
color: #e27803;
}
.dropdownmenulist li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    width: 203px;   
    font-size: 13px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000;
    text-indent: 3px;
    font-weight: 100;
    opacity: 1;

    display: block;

    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdownmenulist {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 17px;
    height: 180px;
}
.dropdownmenulist li{
    border-bottom: thin dotted #888b8e;
    width: 203px;
    padding-bottom: -5px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
.dbordermenulist {
    overflow: auto;
 border-bottom: thin dotted rgba(50,50,52, .7);
 z-index: -1;
 left: 0px;
 width: 203px;
 left: 0px;
 margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74AW4/

I have been playing with it but can't seem to find my mistake..I have posted the css here but the jsfiddle includes the whole html too.

Comment: you have 2 bottom borders on items (the li and div within it) that have negative padding and margin (making them move up). Remove the negative bottom css and i will work: http://jsfiddle.net/74AW4/6/

Comment: remove your margin-bottom :-10px; find out another solution for this.

Comment: you are messing with padding and margin. you can make a reset to zero and then if needed tune them to your needs  http://jsfiddle.net/74AW4/8/ negative padding are not supported

Comment: how come it works on jsfiddle and doesn't on mine Pete? the exact same thing...

Comment: @user3451555 restart from clean by making a reset to zero for padding and margin to <ul> & <li> , negative padding do not work , negative : margin reduces space needed by elements so to use with care. From a clean reset  you can easily set the padding and margin you really need :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying a negative margin to all the `div` elements with a class of `.dbordermenulist`.  Remove the `margin-bottom: -10px` for these elements and that will fix it.

```
.dbordermenulist {
    overflow: auto;
    border-bottom: thin dotted rgba(50,50,52, .7);
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0px;
    width: 203px;
    left: 0px;
    /* margin-bottom: -10px; Remove this */
}
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/74AW4/11/)

Also you have a bottom border applied to both your `li` elements and your `div` elements which create a double border effect.  You may want that but if not that's the reason

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to comment this line of css from .dbordermenulist

```
margin-bottom: -10px;
```

this get your line a bit above and it look like they are cross.

Hope this help.